# Geometry - Inversion/Cross Ratios

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, inversive-geometry

Problem 5. Let ABCD be a given convex quadrilateral with sides BC
and AD equal in length and not parallel. Let E and F be interior points
of the sides BC and AD respectively such that BE = DF. The lines AC
and BD meet at P, the lines BD and EF meet at Q, the lines EF and AC
meet at R. Consider all the triangles P QR as E and F vary. Show that the
circumcircles of these triangles have a common point other than P.

Looking at the segments we know, and using generalised Menelaus we hve
CR/AR = DQ/QB

We now take an inversion about P sending the general point X to X'. 
If we consider a point at infinity P', under inversion this point goes to P. 
And since cross ratios are preserved under inversion, we can say;
[A,P',R,C] = [B,P',Q,D] implies the following
[A',P,R',C'] = [B',P,Q',D']
we know the former is true because of Menelaus and distances from points to a point at infinity are equal.

Does this imply that since we know there exists a point where A'B' meets D'C' and a line through this point T and P, that R'Q' also goes through this point for all R'Q' and so the circles intersect at a fixed point as desired?

If this is not true can someone please explain why and if possible complete the proof with inversion?[image]